# Rfc2898DeriveBytes - password length

Tags: c#, encryption, pbkdf2

Trying to find related answer for a long time, but not convinced yet.

What I am trying is to encrypt using RijndaelManaged. To create Key, I am passing password, salt and iteration to Rfc2898DeriveBytes.

I was thinking to add constant if user entered password is below specific length before passing it to Rfc2898DeriveBytes.

So far what I found that adding constant will not add any benefit to security. Let suppose attacker get an access to database containing encrypted data along with salt, but not to constant will give him a bit harder time. Although in the end he will find that constant.

Or it is "really and extremely" safe to pass any length password to Rfc2898DeriveBytes without getting worried?

Does passing shorter or lengthier password affect key derivation process in term of which one is better and most recommended?

So far what I know that random salt and more iteration is important.

Following is the code, should I remove adding constant to password or keep it?

(Note: password length restriction to user is not applied at GUI, user can pass 1 character or even more than 10 characters)

```
string constant = "AnyConstantToMakePasswordBigger";

if (password.Length < 8) 
{ 
password = password + constant; 
}

RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] salt = new byte[8];

rng.GetBytes(salt);

Rfc2898DeriveBytes derivedKey = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 1000);

using (RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged())
{
     aes.Key = derivedKey.GetBytes(keyLength);
     .....
}
```

Welcoming any positive or negative comment and responses.

Comment: The only solution is to require the user enter a password of at least a certain length. Adding a constant or more rounds isn't going to make up for a 1 character password.

Comment: yes, salt and more iterations are more important.  In fact, more iterations is exactly what BCrypt does.  I don't think adding constant data to make a "longer password" would make much of a difference--you're not changing the effective depth of security of the password.

Comment: Adding the constant is pointless. The salt already achieves the purpose you want the constant to fulfill. Infact, adding the constant has the potential to make secuirty worse (although I think you'll be safe with `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`). If you want to improve security ensure the password excedes a minimum length.

Comment: @Jordell, Even the provided password is of just 1 character length? (please note that the length cannot be restricted at begining)

Comment: How does padding the password with a fixed value help? You want to increase entropy not decrease it.

Comment: Nothing that you do to the passwords (beyond what you've already done as good practice: Salt, iterations, good algorithm) is going to improve security.  If the data really needs to be secure you should encourage good passwords.

Comment: @Jordell, If attacker get access to encrypted data with hash, and if it was encrypted using 1 character password, then within a minute he will able to decrypt. While adding a fixed length constant (knowing attacker doens't have access to it) will make him work harder.  Also I didn't get this part of your comment that adding constant will be potential to make secuirty worse?

Answer (score 0):

With an assumption that the attacker doesn't know the "constant" then, yes, it would effectively increase security by making brute force attacks harder.  HOWEVER, that is a very bad assumption and you should ALWAYS assume the attacker has your source code.

Continuing on our bad assumption: You are correct that the attacker may eventually figure out your constant if enough passwords are cracked.

As to whether or not one adding more characters to your password improves key derivation: not really.  The key that you generate will be the same length no matter what.  But an attacker is not going to attempt to guess your key, they are too long and effectively impossible to brute force.  Any attacker is going to go after the password.

This is where iterations, salt and hard to guess long passwords come in. Iterations increase difficulty by increasing the time it takes to make each guess.  While the time to do thousands of iterations when a legitimate user logs in is negligible,  the cost to a brute force attacker is huge.  Long passwords additionally increase difficulty of brute force.  The salt helps to protect identical passwords from being solved at the same time (the attacker must attack each password independently even if they are the same).

Comment: What is "encryptedness"?  It's hard to say that iterations do or don't increase "encryptedness" if you create a new term no one knows anything about.  You go on to say iterations make it more difficult to brute force attack--thus more secure.  So, if "encryptedness" has to do with security, then you're contradicting yourself.

Comment: @PeterRitchie You're right poor choice of words.  I'll edit now.

Comment: adding a constant to the password decreases the entropy, the very thing `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is designed to increase (with the help of salt).

Comment: @MikeH, In my bad assumption, I think I am getting more convinced towards adding constant to password (as I don't know the provided password will be shorter or longer)... Now, I am at this assumption that what should be the recommended length of password provided to Rfc2898DeriveBytes, I mean the length of constant + password?

Comment: @toughcanny, I encourage you to reread the comments from Jodrell. Actually....I'm confused, you say you're "convinced toward adding constant" but you also ask for a minimum password length.  Could you clarify?

Comment: I am convinced towards adding constant because I want to make user entered password as a good password for Rfc2898DeriveBytes. What I mean from Minimum length password is the (UserEnteredPassword + Constant).Length which will be passed to Rfc2898DeriveBytes. For e.g. user entered 1 character password, so from constant I will add 7 characters to make it 8 characters. So what would be the recommended password length

Comment: I can't provide a good answer to that question.  As Jodrell mentions, adding a constant decreases entropy.  The longer the constant the less entropy.  However a longer password is usually better. I imagine that there is a balance somewhere, but I don't know what it is.